# Removing entities from another entity

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine, entitymanager

To make it simple, let's say I have two objects with one-to-many relation:

> User --(1:n)--> Request

with User defined as

```
class User {
...
/** @OneToMany(targetEntity="Request", mappedBy="user", cascade={"all"}) */
   private $request;
...
}
```

and Request defined as

```
class Request {
...
/** @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="request", cascade={"persist"}) */
    private $user;
...
}
```

Is it possible to create a method that removes all Requests associated with User **from within** User entity?

What I need is something like this:

```
class User {
....
    public function removeAllMyRequests() {
        foreach ($this->getAllMyRequests() as $req)
            $this->em->remove($req);
    }
....
}
```

But apparently I'm not supposed to invoke entity manager from within entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mark the association with ["Orphan Removal"](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#orphan-removal):

```php
/** 
 * @Entity 
 */
class User
{
    /** 
     * @OneToMany(
     *   targetEntity="Request",
     *   mappedBy="user", 
     *   cascade={"all"}, 
     *   orphanRemoval=true
     * ) 
     */
    private $requests;
}
```

Any `Request` object removed from the `User#requests` collection will be marked for removal during the next `EntityManager#flush()` call.

To remove all items at once, you can simply use `Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection#clear()`:

```
public function removeAllMyRequests() {
    $this->requests->clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the "cascade" option : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations

Comment: I guess simple cascading is not enough. Both entities already support cascading (cascade='persist', cascade='all'). I **don't have access** to entity manager from User class, so I'm not able to use $em->remove() or $em->persist() methods.